# Join with count conditition

Tags: sql, sql-server

Consider the following Schema:

**Table Invoices:**

`Id|TotalSum|Status`

`1|12|1`

`1|13|0`

**Table ClientInvoices:**

`Id|ClientId|InvoiceId`

Table "invoices" may contain multiple invoices with the same Id but with different status (there is unique constraint on Id and status.). Status is integer that represents enum (0 - inactive, 1 - active)

I want to get all the client invoices with price changes if any:

`ClientId|InvoiceId|SumBefore|SumAfter`

If there is no inactive invoices then PreviousPrice should be null. I am trying to achieve this using the following query:

```
SELECT Clients.Id AS ClientId,
Invoice.Id AS InvoiceId,
ActualInvoice.TotalSum AS SumBefore,
InActiveInvoice.TotalSum AS SumAfter
FROM Invoices
LEFT JOIN ClientInvoices AS ActualInvoice ON ActualInvoice.InvoiceId AND Status = 1
LEFT JOIN ClientInvoices AS Inactive ON ActualInvoice.InvoiceId AND Status = 0
LEFT JOIN Clients ON Clients.Id = ClientInvoices.ClientId
```

This works well if there are two records for one invoice: past(inative) and current. However if there is only one invoice - it has active status and using the query above I get `SumBefore` = null and `SumAfter` = value which should be in `SumBefore` column.

It would be great if I could specify to join record on condition if count of row of that record is f.e. 1. Is that possible?

Comment: yes you can ...you can sub query in using [HAVING Clause](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp)

Comment: I would start with a `left join` of `Invoices` to itself where on the left you hold `status=1` and then `status=0`. Then join the result to `ClientInvoices`
I think this should get you the sums aligned correctly:
    `select 
    a.InvoiceId as InvoiceId, 
    a.TotalSum as SumBefore, 
    b.TotalSum as SumAfter 
    from 
    Invoices a left join Invoices b on a.InvoiceId = b.InvoiceId
    and a.status=1 and b.status=0`
And then you can join the result to ClientsInvoices

Comment: Why join with Clients? If you want info for currrent clients only, say so & give Clients columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
select c.ClientId as ClientId,
a.InvoiceId as InvoiceId,
a.TotalSum as SumBefore, 
b.TotalSum as SumAfter
from Invoices a left join Invoices b
on a.InvoiceId = b.InvoiceId
and a.status = 1 and b.status = 0
join ClientsInvoices c on c.InvoiceId = a.InvoiceId
```